# Image binding in gridview and div in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to bind image in my list page(at grid view) and detail page(at div).

At list page, I used the following sentence and it works.

```
ImageUrl='<%#string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgURL"].ToString() + "/{0}",Eval("ImgID")) %>'
```

Note:

- `ImgURL` is the key from `web.config`
- `ImgID` is value from data-table.

At detail page, I used the same pattern to show image at div portion. However, it does not seem to work. Could somebody tell me what am I missing out?

```
ImageUrl='<%#string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgURL"].ToString() + "/{0}",ImgID) %>'
```

Note:

- `ImgURL` is the key from `web.config`
- `ImgID` is String value from source code file

Comment: What does the generated html look like?

Comment: Blank value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to add a `Databind()` call in your `Page_Load` of your detail page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Reference:

- [ASP.NET data binding overview](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307860/asp.net-data-binding-overview#1a)

> After the particular data sources have been determined and set for the objects on the .aspx page, you must bind the data to these data sources. You can use the Page.DataBind or the Control.DataBind method to bind the data to the data sources.
>   [...]
>   No data is rendered to the control until you explicitly call either the DataBind method of the Web server control or until you invoke the page-level Page.DataBind method. Typically, Page.DataBind (or DataBind) is called from the Page_Load event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even I added this , it can't work. When I output it as label , the image path is correct.

Comment: Is the image path correct when you output is as label with or without the `Eval`?

Comment: Without the Eval, it is correct. With the Eval, show blank.

Comment: Did you try my last update? Use `DataBind()` in your `Page_Load` and not using the `Eval`.

Comment: I have DataBind() method for imgID on Page_Load(). As label , imgID can show correct values on screen. Thanks.

Comment: Not yet. Show blank instead of image.

Comment: How did you call `DataBind()` in your `Page_Load`?

Comment: After checking some points and data refer process, made data binding process.

Comment: // check some session value. Then, if(!IsPostBack) { //Refer Data from DB //DataBind } .... Which point do you want me to check in coding?

Comment: <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgURL"].ToString() + "/{0}","test") %>'></asp:Label>  , I tested by changing this style and it shows Blank. I think it is not because of behind coding but because of missing in binding UI. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it out the problem by inputting imageUrl from source file(.aspx.cs).
It is just working and I still don't know why can't render on UI page. 
Thank you all. ^_^

```
img.ImageUrl=string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["imgURL"].ToString() + "/{0}", imgID);
```